# Can I use AWS Glue to run Apache pig script?

Tags: data-analysis, s3

Can I use AWS Glue to run Apache pig script? If not, is there any alternative tool/service in AWS that can run pig jobs? We are moving from on-prem to AWS and want to see which tools would best suffice our need.

Need: Read data from S3 and process it (via pig script) and load it to another s3 bucket.

Comment: This sounds like a question for https://superuser.com/  Are you asking how to do something (https://superuser.com/)? Or asking for some software to do it (on topic here)?

Comment: @Mawg we are using glue to run pyspark spripts, so wanted to see if I can use Glue to run pig scripts. Also learnt that AWS Data Pipeline is a similar tool, but want to make sure the Glue does not have that capability and then I can move on to trying Data Pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the expatiation, but it doesn't seem to answer my question : "` Are you asking how to do something (superuser.com)? Or asking for some software to do it (on topic here)?`" Since that is not very clear, you are unlikely to get an answer  anywhere, until you edit your question. Please read [ask]. Good luck

Comment: Just curious, what were your findings regarding running pig scripts in glue?